# Google Map API v3 - Getting Clustered Markers Info on same spot

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Have been using google map api v3 to display my marker but I realize that clustered marker on the exact latLong will overlap one another which seems perfectly reasonable.

Thus I will like to solve this by returning all clustered marker's information within a configurable radius and display it on a console. Is it possible to return marker's information on click?

Comment: What does your code look like?  How are you planning on "clicking" on the markers under the top one?

Comment: You might want to look at the [OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-maps-api-3%5D+OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier)

Comment: @geocodezip Hello, I am actually using overlapping marker spiderfier already. My current codes works exactly how OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier should work. When ('click') clicking on a clustered marker, it separates. However I would like to archive the following instead, when 'click' it returns a value "hello world". My current code for this listener is oms.addListener('click', function(marker, event){ console.log(/*Hello world prints here*/); });

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: @geocodezip Hello, as I have mention earlier, my code works exactly how OMS works, thus it is not an issue. It works exactly like https://jawj.github.io/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier/demo.html , however my intention was not have the marker expand, instead, I altered the OMS code to return a value, thus my question was, how do I pass back this value upon clicking on a clustered marker... Nevertheless I'm trying to work on a solution simply by using the source code right on the interface level